# I want to get all products from opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I need a query to get all products from opencart mysql. I am using this query.

```
"SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product`";
```

but I can't get product name or title in this query. Actually I am creating another application and I want to export all products into new DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real sql

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY pd.name ASC
```

First take oc_ into consideration as this is DB_PREFIX.
Then take pd.language_id='1' into consideration as it retrieves products only having language_id=1. If there are multiple language then you have to find the language_id and change it.

This is to retrieve all

```
SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me. I am going to solve this answer.. Can you please solve one more problem. image column in product table doesn't return resized image filename. How can get I?